# The execution of my java code only works with `java -cp . Main`, not `java Main`

Tags: java, cmd, classpath

Why does this work in executing my code:

```
java -cp . Main
```

but not this:

```
java Main
```

I have always used just `java <classname>` for executing my code, however almost randomly, this command just provides the error message `Error: Could not find or load main class Main`.

Here's my Java file (Main.java):

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
  }
}
```

[Here's the output from my Command Prompt including file names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK0Tn.png)

Comment: Isn't that the usual way to execute class files that are in the same directory? I have always used that method and it has weirdly never given me a problem before. Is there some specific reason as to why `java Main` would not work?

Comment: I just tried the java Main in command line and it worked well. I am not sure why it didn't work with you.

Comment: Check your `CLASSPATH` environment variable. If that's specified, then it's used; and if it doesn't contain `.`, then you have to explicitly specify on the command line.

Comment: I've just checked for the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, and I didn't already have it included. However, it results in the same `Error: Could not find or load main class Main` with just `java Main`. Thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: Did you change the value of CLASSPATH? What is it now?

Comment: The full text is now `C:\libraries\junit-4.12.jar;C:\libraries\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;.`

I tried it also with an extra `;` at the end, stil the same output.